# Creating a Dynamic Range that works for Excel to Save Name Ranges to a Static Web Page

Tags: excel, dynamic, static, named-ranges, save-as

I have a excel document that has several name ranges that are currently save to static web pages. I have recently tried to conver them to dynamic ranges, and have learned the dynamic named ranges work great within the context of the excel sheet itself, but fail once excel tries to save them as the static web page.

For example, I have a range

YardTabletLists!$EC$1:$EE$101

sometimes the content is exceeds the bounds or I have empty rows on my webpage.

the dynamic alternative is

=OFFSET(YardTabletLists!$EC$1,0,0,COUNTA(YardTabletLists!$EC$1:$EC$10000)+1,3)

If i refernce this name range anywhere within the sheet, it works, but when AutoPublish does it thing, I get the following error.

[Error Notice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSuvt.png)

I was thinking of trying to conver the Dynamic range back to a static range somehow, and then direct the name rage to that Cell.... i.e.

Name range is directed to =E4, and E4 contains YardTabletLists!$EC$1:$EE$101, but I get the feeling that will give me the same issue.

Thanks to those who read this.

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with static webpage feature.

But possible to define and use “table” instead of “named range”?

With “table” Excel internally handles the correct range whenever the table size is modified.

Seems the static webpage feature supports also “filtered ranges”. Could this be a work-around, e.g. to filter out blank lines (while using max line number as static range)?

Indirect references (your example with E4) are a little tricky in Excel. I only used it once to define a list for a dropdown.
Muss be supported by the feature and requires “special” syntax

Update:

I have found some examples for VBA updating name ranges, and one excellent example that appears to answer the question:

https://excelchamps.com/vba/named-range/#Resizing_a_Named_Range_using_VBA_Dynamic_Named_Range

```
Sub vba_named_range()

Dim iRow As Long
Dim iColumn As Long

iRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
iColumn = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column

ActiveSheet.Range("myRange") _
.Resize(iRow, iColumn).Name = "myRange"

End Sub
```

for some reason the program hangs up at

ActiveSheet.Range("myRange") _
.Resize(iRow, iColumn).Name = "myRange"

does anyone see perhaps a syntax error I am missing?

Thank you :)

Comment: The problem with a table as that adding lines of data extends the table, but removing lines does not. I need the range to exactly match the data set.

That said using a simple dynamic range calc that results in the text for the dynamic range and then adding =indirect(AE4) as described above does not work. I am not looking into the VBA of it...and I am horrible at VBA so hopefully I am able to find someone who can get my started.

thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: I am not sure whether we talking about the same thing regarding tables: to be sure I just tested it. The defined table adjusts its range according to the range in both cases reducing/increasing the number of rows.

Comment: To avoid misunderstandings: above I was referring to the tables defined via the GUI (similar to named ranges). Once defined as table, adding/deleting rows are reflected in the range of the table dynamically